# How do I test both the success and .catch in this function

Tags: jasmine

Can anyone point me in the right direction to test both the success and .catch scenarios in this function? I don't know how to mock my resource properly to do this.

```
        function loadData() {
        cisVersionResource.get({ 'cisId': vm.cisId })
            .$promise.then(function(data) {
                vm.newContractSum = data.contractSum;
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                logger.warning('CIS Retrieve Warning', 'unable to retrieve CIS information', response.data);
            });

    }
```